# How to store camera permission in ios PWA?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, ios-permissions, angular-pwa

I have created an application using angular PWA and it has a barcode scan functionality. It's working fine in ios but the problem is that every time use comes on this page it's asking for camera permission each time even if the user gave it once, PWA will ask for the permission again.

Is there any way that I can store the permission once the user allowed camera and use that permission so that it will not ask the user each time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, only native apps can receive permanent permissions as they have a settings screen in the system settings app where the user can revoke the permission.

Comment: ThanksPaulw11 for your answer. I thought the same but I was thinking if someone knows any other way possible.

Comment: There is a related WebKit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=215884